# CMake can not find SFML lib

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I have a project depends on SFML lib on C++. I trying to make it with CMake.
CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(3D_Renderer_from_scratch)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(headers source)

set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)

find_package(SFML COMPONENTS window graphics system)

set(SOURCES
        Main.cpp
        source/Application.cpp
        source/Box.cpp
        source/Camera.cpp
        source/FileReader.cpp
        source/KeyboardHandler.cpp
        source/Sphere.cpp
        source/Triangle.cpp
        source/Window.cpp
        source/World.cpp
        )

add_executable(executable ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(executable ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
```

After running `cmake .` I have the following error:

```
$ cmake .
-- Requested SFML configuration (Static) was not found
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake

  but it set SFML_FOUND to FALSE so package "SFML" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mcjohn974/3D_Renderer_from_scratch
```

How can I fix it ? (sfml lib is already installed)

Comment: "Requested SFML configuration (Static) was not found" - It seems your SFML installation contains only **shared** libraries and no **static** ones. Note, that standard SFML packages (like the [one on Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libsfml-graphics2.5/filelist)) provides only shared libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks a lot, can you help how can I link shared library via CMake ?

Comment: `target_link_libraries` works both with shared and static libraries. Just remove the line `set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)` from your code, so your project could use shared SFML libraries, which are actually installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments (why not write it as an answer?), CMake was looking for static SFML libraries and it most likely just found shared libraries.

Either make sure that static libraries (the ones with the -s suffix) are provided.
Or don't request static libraries, which you can achieve be not setting `SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES`.